# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'welcomeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userValidator'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Ive been trying to get my head around this error for hours now with little success.

Im getting the following error -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'welcomeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userValidator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.config.UserValidator' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My WelcomeController has an AutoWired to UserValidator -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class WelcomeController {

    @Autowired
    AuctionItemRepository aucRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserValidator userValidator;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    SecurityService securityService;

// inject via application.properties
@Value("${welcome.message:test}")
private String message = "Hello World";

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", this.message);
    return "welcome";
}


    Date getTime() {
        Timestamp time = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        return time;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/sell", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addAuction(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {


        model.addAttribute("newAuction", new AuctionItem());
        model.addAttribute("action", "sell");
        return "NewAuction";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/sell", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAuction(@ModelAttribute("AuctionItem")AuctionItem auction, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "error";
        }
 //           User user = (User) userRepository.findByUsername(getUser());
        auction.setAucStartTime(getTime());

        aucRepository.save(auction);
//            AuctionItem ai = aucRepository.findByOwnerAndStartTime(user, auction.getaStart());
        return "redirect:/aucConfirm";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/aucConfirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String confirmAuction(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {


        return "aucConfirm";
    }





    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
        return "register";
    }   


    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

        return "login";
    }
```

}

UserValidator Class -

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator{
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return User.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
            User user = (User) o;

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "NotEmpty");
    if (user.getUsername().length() < 6 || user.getUsername().length() > 32) {
        errors.rejectValue("username", "Size.userForm.username");
    }
    if (userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
        errors.rejectValue("username", "Duplicate.userForm.username");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "NotEmpty");
    if (user.getPass().length() < 8 || user.getPass().length() > 32) {
        errors.rejectValue("password", "Size.userForm.password");
    }

    if (!user.getPasswordConfirm().equals(user.getPass())) {
        errors.rejectValue("passwordConfirm", "Diff.userForm.passwordConfirm");
    }
}

}
```

Both these classes as well as my Spring Boot Configuration and WebSecurityConfig are in the package com.config

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `UserValidator` doesn't seem to be annotated with `@Component` or similar.

Comment: Yep that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `@Component` stereotype annotation for your `UserValidator` class, otherwise, Spring container will not instantiate that class & therefore will not be able to inject it as a dependency inside `WelcomeController`.

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator{
 //add current code
}
```